# ignore remote changes to a specific, ignored file

Tags: git, gitignore, git-merge-conflict

In our git repository for a latex project, pdf files are set to be ignored. Some still manage to push the compiled pdf, which makes the occasional **pull a conflict between my local and the remote pdf**, as it returns: "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"

Is there a git feature that does this: "always ignore remote changes to this file", ideally synced with what's listed in the `.gitignore`?

I could solve this
(1) by agreeing that no ones pushes files that are on the ignore list and reverting the corresponding changes (several mixed commits by now),
(2a) by ignoring *my* changes via an alias for `rm that-file.pdf && git pull` or similarly
(2b) by backing up that file and overwriting the pulled change. Or
(3) I could always build my latex-project into a build folder, and remember that when I need the current pdf.

Answers for similar problems:

- [pushing the pdf removal for everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461850/5864166) is a good approach, but I don't want to cause remote changes in that matter (let us assume the person pushing the PDF is happy to be able to open the file from the web-interface, too)
- [force git pull](https://fjolt.com/article/git-force-overwrite-with-git-pull) via `git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master` would not only overwrite my pdf (which is ok, although I'd prefer to ignore the *remote* change), but I'd risk losing local changes out of the .gitignore scope, too.
- [`--assume-unchanged`](https://practicalgit.com/blog/make-git-ignore-local-changes-to-tracked-files.html) is getting in the right direction, but cannot handle regular updates to the remote pdf
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55161877/5864166) is similar, but asks to skip all conflicting remote updates (while I appreciate a pull failing due to a conflict, as long it doesn't concern a file on the ignore list)

edit:

**git hooks** are potentially helpful here (see comments below).

- Unfortunately, [pre-pull hooks don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185400/is-there-any-git-hook-for-pull) although they could help individuals keeping a normal workflow without asking other people anything.
- A *server-side hook* can [reject the commit with an error message](https://coolaj86.com/articles/server-side-git-hooks-for-code-formatting/) and maybe it can also just rename the commited pdf
- A [client-side pre-commit
  hook](https://verdantfox.com/blog/view/how-to-use-git-pre-commit-hooks-the-hard-way-and-the-easy-way)
  can help to avoid commits not respecting the `.gitignore`

Comment: Perhaps the way to go is with hooks to _avoid_ people from committing changes to PDF files..... also, reject PRs that mess up with PDFs.

Comment: Do you mean a server-side hook that removes the pdf from the commit or is there a way to reject the commit with a custom message (automatizing the explanation effort would be great)? Nevertheless, I'm fine with one person having a license to push the pdf, I just want to keep pulling everything else. Maybe that hook could rename it, adding the commiter's name ;-)

Comment: I don't think so _though_ it's not like I know all of the possibilities when dealing with hooks. I was thinking more of a **commit** hook, which is something that would run when developers **commit** so it's a **client-side** (I would be included to call it _local_) thing.

Comment: The others would need to install client-side hooks by editing a local-only file in `.git/hooks`, I think that is much effort for them. I could provide a hook definition and ask them to move it to the right place - or can I commit in the `.git/hooks` subdirectory directly? https://pre-commit.com allows to define the procedure in a versioned `.pre-commit-config.yaml` in the repository root, but it is to be separately installed by every user.

Answer (score 0):

Every Git repository clone is private and you cannot stop anyone from doing anything they want with their own personal private clone.  That leaves you with only two *guaranteed* options:

- Set up some sort of controls on a centralized repository to which people push (e.g., GitHub's "protected branches"); and/or
- Don't take their commits as-is with `git pull`.  Avoid `git pull` entirely.  Use `git fetch`, *inspect* the incoming commits, and reject (or add fixup commits to) their commits if they are incorrect.

You *can* ask collaborators to install correct `.gitignore` files and/or pre-commit hooks, but they're equally free to ignore your pleas.  Once a bad commit exists, it literally cannot be fixed: at most, you can make a new commit that's like the bad commit, but improved, either as a replacement (which is generally a headache but may eventually save space in the repository as the PDFs may be large) or as an add-on commit (generally safer, Git does the right things here).

Here's an example command sequence that adds a fixup commit when Person X (the bad guy) commits some pdf file that he should not have:

- `git fetch`: get their new commit(s)
- `git log --stat ..@{u}`: observe what they did
- If they did it wrong:

  ```
  git worktree add -b fix-yet-another-person-x-screwup ../fixup @{u}
  pushd ../fixup
  git rm wrongfile.pdf
  git commit -m 'rm incorrectly added pdf'
  git push origin HEAD:whatever-the-branch-is
  popd
  git fetch
  ```

  Assuming all has gone well at this point, you can now `git worktree remove` the added working tree (`../fixup` in this example) and it is now safe to run `git merge` as usual.

You can even build an automated system to check for bad commits (perhaps only bothering to check the ones from known bad guys).

Note that Person X won't see your branch names unless you show them to him, so you can be as snarky as you like with them.  (But beware of accidentally showing them, which is pretty easy to do by mistake.)

Comment: Right, we _cannot stop anyone from doing anything they want_ - this is the spirit of my question. Regularly pushing commits deleting their compiled pdfs again, is not (though my first reaction would have also been a feature branch where the feature is respect for our `.gitignore`). An ignore-list should be treated by a git client (at least optionally) like an "Even if my colleagues do, I really don't care about these files" -list. Maybe I should contribute that feature?

Comment: You could try: there's definitely something that needs to be done with `.gitignore` handling. Junio has mentioned more than once the need for a distinction between "don't add this file but don't destroy it either" vs "don't add this file and do feel free to destroy it" (`.gitignore` sometimes means the latter!). However, this is a very tricky part of Git internally.